# Is centre of a circle remains invarient under Movius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

> Prove that the image of the center of a given circle is never the same as that of the circle image under a linear fractional map.

Given some linear fractional map$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, that is $ad-bc\neq0, c\neq0$ and a circle on $\Bbb C$ not passing through $z_0=\frac{-d}{c}$, so that the image is another circle, prove that the image of the center of the given circle is never the same as that of the image.

$a, b, c, d\in\Bbb R$ and $z\in\Bbb C$

I'm not sure how to generalize this proof for any circle with the given specifications and its image under the linear fractional map.

Answer (score 2):

By composing $f$ with affine maps before and after, we can assume WLOG that the linear fractional map is $z \to 1/z$, and the centre of the first circle is at $p$ on the nonnegative real axis.  The radius is $r>0$ where $r \ne p$.  The image of $0$ is $\infty$, which is not the centre of a circle, so we can assume $p \ne 0$.
The closest and farthest points to $0$ on the circle are at 
$p-r$ and $p+r$.  Their images $1/(p-r)$ and $1/(p+r)$ are the farthest and closest points to $0$ on the image of the circle, so the centre of that image is
at 
$$ q = \dfrac{1}{2(p-r)} + \dfrac{1}{2(p+r)}$$
Simplify $q - 1/p$ and you'll see that $q \ne 1/p$.

Comment: If you down vote please explain why you disagree